# Is there a way to automatically generate an ID/UUID in RML?

Tags: json, xml, mapping, turtle-rdf, rml-rdf

I am currently mapping a JSON file through RML, and the file I'm mapping doesn't have any ID's that I can use. Is there any way to generate an ID through RML, or is doing something like this impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask"). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the snippet editor.